# Android Runtime error android manifest fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

I implemented an Android Activity in a Fragment and I got a runtime error.

> 04-20 09:52:18.659  31722-31722/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.test.test, PID: 31722
>       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.test.test/com.test.test.MainFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java)

But I cannot declare it in the manifest, because it is not an Activity.

Comment: show code. Probably you use startActivity with fragment...

Comment: have you declared your main activity in manifest.xml where you call your fragment?

Comment: i have start activity inside fragment so that fragment starts an activity but therre is no start activity that starts fragment.

Comment: You can't implement activity in fragment.

Answer (score 1):

A fragment should be a part of activity. And an activity must be declared in android manifest.
There are different ways to start an activity and fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments when included with an activity is cool... you can add smooth work flow for your apps. each of your activity needs to be registered in manifest.xml

Your One activity can hold multiple Fragments (through a common Framelayout like view) and you can switch between screens (or do fragment transactions) with animation and effects.

Explore : Adding fragment to Activity, Fragment transaction, Popping backstack etc.

Most of the popular and large data apps are using fragments for better user experience.